# jQuery event handler logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I'm having a problem figuring out where I'm going wrong in my code that is supposed to automatically fill in "railQuantity" for a form I am building. Currently my code only "works" when either 6ft or 8ft "fenceHeight" is selected but either way it uses the total = (Math.ceil(footage / 8) * 3); equation. It will, however, correctly blank out when I choose "Select Fence Height". So I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong with my logic so that it does not correctly use the equation for the corresponding fenceHeight. Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks you guys!

Html snippet:

Fence Description:

```
<select name="fenceHeight" id="fenceHeight">
    <option value="select">Select Fence Height</option>
    <option value="4" id="fH4">4 Ft.</option>
    <option value="6" id="fH6">6 Ft.</option>
    <option value="8" id="fH8">8 Ft.</option>
</select>
```

Javascript snippet:

```
//Quantity for Rails
$('#fenceHeight, #footage').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function() {
    var footage = parseFloat($(':input[name="footage"]').val(),10);
    var total = '';
    if($(':input[name="fenceHeight"]').val() != "select"){
        if(parseFloat($(':input[name="fenceHeight"]').val() == "8")) {
            total = (Math.ceil(footage / 8)* 4);
        } 
        if(parseFloat($(':input[name="fenceHeight"]').val() == "4" || "6")) {
            total = (Math.ceil(footage / 8) * 3);
        } 
        $(':input[name="railQuantity"]').val(total.toString());
    } else {
        $(':input[name="railQuantity"]').val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you calling `parseFloat`, but then comparing the results with strings instead of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $footage = $('#footage'),
    $fenceHeight = $('#fenceHeight'),
    $railQuantity = $('input[name="railQuantity"]');
$footage.add($fenceHeight).bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function () {
    var footage = parseFloat($footage.val(), 10),
        fenceHeight = $fenceHeight.val();
    var total = '';
    if (fenceHeight != NaN) {
        if (fenceHeight == '8') {
            total = (Math.ceil(footage / 8) * 4);
        }
        if (fenceHeight == '4' || fenceHeight == '6') {
            total = (Math.ceil(footage / 8) * 3);
        }
        $railQuantity.val(total);
    } else {
        $railQuantity.val('');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a4nDY/)

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I was wondering why exactly the '$' for $railQuantity is required for that var in the code but not for the others, any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

These lines are wrong:

```
    if(parseFloat($(':input[name="fenceHeight"]').val() == "8")) {
        total = (Math.ceil(footage / 8)* 4);
    } 
    if(parseFloat($(':input[name="fenceHeight"]').val() == "4" || "6")) {
        total = (Math.ceil(footage / 8) * 3);
    }
```

You're not comparing the result of `parseFloat` with the strings, you're comparing the `val()` with the strings and passing the result of the comparison to parseFloat. And in the second one, you're comparing `val()` with the result of `4 || 6`, which is `4` -- you can't combine comparisons with `or` in programming languages like you can in English. Change it to:

```
    var height = $(':input[name="fenceHeight"]').val();
    if (height == "8") {
        total = (Math.ceil(footage / 8)* 4);
    } else if (height == "4" || height == "6") {
        total = (Math.ceil(footage / 8) * 3);
    }
```